# Difference between Object and *?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

What should be used while declaring a variable as below:

```
private var someVar:*;
```

OR

```
private var someVar:Object;
```

What is the difference between the two?
What makes one superior then other in various situations? Any examples?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`someVar:*` is a special untyped var that holds the default value `undefined` while

`Object` var default value is `null`.

That's the only key difference.

Answer (score 9):

From the [Adobe Documentation,](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=03_Language_and_Syntax_11.html)

```
private var someVar:*;
private var someVar:Object;
```

> In previous versions of ActionScript, a variable with no type
>   annotation was automatically assigned the Object data type. This is no
>   longer true in ActionScript 3.0, which now includes the idea of a
>   truly untyped variable. Variables with no type annotation are now
>   considered untyped. If you prefer to make it clear to readers of your
>   code that your intention is to leave a variable untyped, you can use
>   the new asterisk (*) symbol for the type annotation, which is
>   equivalent to omitting a type annotation. The following example shows
>   two equivalent statements, both of which declare an untyped variable
>   x: